# How to substract two stdout lists in linux bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, grep, stdout

heed help.

I have one list "A" from

```
netstat -ntlp | grep -oP ":[:1]?[:1]?(.*)+" | grep -oP "\d\d+"
```

it looks like

```
80
443
8080
22
25
```

I have another list "B" from

```
ufw status numbered | grep -oP "\] \d+" | grep -oP "\d+"
```

it looks as

```
80
443
22
```

So i want to know, which ports are listening, but not open with ufw, i.e. substract ["A"]-["B"]
and going to see

```
8080
25
```

with some command like

```
netstat -ntlp | grep -oP ":[:1]?[:1]?(.*)+" | grep -oP "\d\d+" | SELECT ALL NOT IN `ufw status numbered | grep -oP "\] \d+" | grep -oP "\d+"`
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically it's `comm` job:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep -oP ":[:1]?[:1]?(.*)+" | grep -oP "\d\d+" |
sort | comm -23 - <(ufw status numbered | grep -oP "\] \d+" | grep -oP "\d+" | sort)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `grep`:

```
grep -vxFf <(cmd2) <(cmd1)
```

Here replace `cmd1` with `netstat ...` command and replace `cmd2` with `ufw ...` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `uniq -u` command:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html

You pass a group of lines to uniq -d and redirect to an output. It will print only the duplicated ones.
So you just need to aggregate both results from list A and list B into a text:

List A:

`netstat -ntlp | grep -oP ":[:1]?[:1]?(.*)+" | grep -oP "\d\d+" >> output.txt`

List B:

`ufw status numbered | grep -oP "\] \d+" | grep -oP "\d+" > output.txt` >> output.txt`

(NOTE: You use '>>' over '>' to append the content to end of the file. So make sure to clean it on each iteration!)

Then:

`uniq -u output.txt`

You can redirect the uniq -u output too, if needed:

`uniq -u output.txt > gotuniques.txt`

Edit: formatting
Edit2: I was confused by -d when the answer requires -u.

Comment: Well, if OP actually read my post and went to the MAN doc of uniq, he could've seen that he/she only needs to change -d for -u and get the "unique" lines instead of the duplicated ones. I am updating my answer tho.

Comment: You also need to sort the output: `sort output.txt | uniq -u`.  Running `uniq` on unsorted data does not work in the intended way.

Answer (score 1):

This solution requires pre-sorting of the outputs:

```
$ netstat -ntlp | grep -oP ":[:1]?[:1]?(.*)+" | grep -oP "\d\d+" | sort > A
                                                                 ^^^^^^
$ ufw status numbered | grep -oP "\] \d+" | grep -oP "\d+" | sort > B
                                                           ^^^^^^
```

Items unique to A:

```
$ comm -23 A B
25
8080
$
```

... but also, in case you require, items unique to B:

```
$ comm -13 A B
$
```

... and items common to A and B:

```
$ comm -12 A B
22
443
80
$
```

See `man comm` for details.